# Show all Chrome bookmarks on one computer and only some on another computer

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I don't think this is possible, but am hoping!

I have a google account my Chrome browser at home is logged into, with all my favourites, which are in different folders and on the favourites bar. When I log in on my work computer, I use IE by default. I do have Chrome installed though, for personal use.

I want to be able to open Chrome and login to my google account. However, there are several sites I have on my personal computer that are not work related (e.g. gaming). As I've so many bookmarks, it would be very helpful if I could do something to de-sync these sites so they didn't appear on my account when accessed from my work computer, but did appear when accessed from my personal computer.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I can't think of a way.  There isn't a large amount of people that want to sync their bookmarks across computers but only include some of them.  Have you considering just exporting the bookmarks you want then importing just those bookmarks at work?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I didn't even know I could do that. I'll have to research how

Comment: I known xmarks can do this.  You can set some folders to sync with specific computers.  A web based bookmarking service like pinboard might also be worth looking at.